# How do I close mysql connection after if-statement if it is true?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, try-catch

I'm new to ASP.NET and I'm stuck on this problem. I get the error:
Error:System.InvalidOperationException: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open. at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.
Here is my code, the error points towards 'while' statement. I've tried number of things but nothing worked. I know that I need to close connection when if-statement is true but don't know how. Can anyone help me on this? Thanks.

```
protected void loadtour()
    {
        try
        {

            conn.Open();
            string strSelect = "Select * From Agents where Agent_ID='" + AgID.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSelect, conn);
            SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                if (myReader["Agent_Status"].ToString() == "On Tour")
                {
                    Label1.Text = "Assigned Tour Details:";
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT PackageInfo.pkg_Name, PackageInfo.pkg_Type, PackageInfo.pkg_Status, Packages.pkg_Country, Packages.pkg_Start, Packages.pkg_End, PackageInfo.Agent_ID, PackageInfo.Agent_Name FROM PackageInfo INNER JOIN Packages ON PackageInfo.pkg_ID = Packages.pkg_ID WHERE(PackageInfo.Agent_ID = '" + AgID.Text + "')", conn);
                        DataTable ds = new DataTable();
                        da.Fill(ds);
                        gv1.DataSource = ds;
                        gv1.DataBind();

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
                    }
                    conn.Close();

                }


                else
                {
                    Label1.Text = "No Tour Assigned Yet!";
                }

                myReader.Close();
                conn.Close();

            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  connection.Open();
  //Do stuff with the connection
}
```

Wrap your connection in a `using` block. This guarantees it always gets closed.